# How can I change the yellow color of Highlighted text when using ctrl+f in chrome using css?

Tags: css

I have changed background color of google chrome to black and foreground (text) color to white, because this is easy for my eyes.
So, when I use ctrl+f to find any word on any page, the highlighted yellow color  makes difficult to see the text.
How can I change this other than yellow USING CSS (userStyleSheet) ? I have googled a long but couldn't find any solution.

Comment: Are you making a website?

Comment: As noted in the comments to [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11592040/is-it-possible-to-style-search-selection-in-firefox) it seems like it's a no-go. Even if you manipulate the text after a search has been done and somehow edit the DOM, it still remains the same.

Comment: sure it's a no-go, because that is implemented by the browser and not the website

Comment: @Mr. Sven Bieder  "But I can change the color and font of pages appear in my browser using css, so I guess There may any way to do the above.However any extension if you know?"

Comment: @Mr.Pavlo - I am not making any website, I want to customize css of chrome.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to try to answer what you need (given the additional info you have given in your comment above) rather than what you asked.

The highlighting color when using [live search / quick find](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/bbedit/eZu9MBvpgN0) is managed by the browser directly. I am not sure how it is implemented, maybe by CSS, but it may also be hardcoded outside of a stylesheet.

However, an extension called [FreshEyes](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fresheyes/bgeggmjapkmjgniljnkgnbncpifgbnlk/) ([source code of FreshEyes is here](https://github.com/cmac2454/fresh-eyes)), is able to change the live search color in Chrome, so maybe you can have a look at how it's doing that?